# Tips for using TEX / LaTeX for writing meeting protocols

Tags: tex-core

I found TEX / LaTeX just over a week ago and I am very pleased with it. I used to hate writing documents on the computer because it felt so inefficient and messy with the word processors. TEX was surprisingly simple to learn and it has made my life so much more convenient.

I am politically active in a socialist youth organization. We write protocols after meeting and I would love to be able to use TEX to do this. I have searched a little bit online but I could not find much information about how to do this.

What are your tips towards writing meetings protocols  in TEX?

Our meeting protocols typically have this structure:

> ## Protocol for member meeting YYYY-MM-DD
>
> Present: *Name, Name, ...* and *Name*
>
> 1. Point one
>
>    a) Part 1...
>
>    b) Part 2...
>
>    c) Part 3...
> 2. Point two
>
>    Text in point two...
> 3. Point three
>
>    Text in point three...
> 4. Meetings ending
>
>    The meeting was finished by *Name*.

How can I efficiently write a document with this structure in TEX / LaTeX?

Comment: Just create a `tex` document that you use as a template (i.e. that you copy before editing): I guess the `\section{…}`, `\subsection{…}`, `\begin{itemize}\item…\end{itemize}`, `\begin{description}\item…\end{description}`, `\begin{enumerate}\item…\end{enumerate}` are enough for what you want. As time goes by, you'll refine that template, but my advice would be *not* to try to settle that template "once and for all" before using it: as you use it, you'll discover limitations, and how to remedy them. You can't foresee all your futures needs.

Comment: And, as often with LaTeX, [there's a package for that](http://ctan.org/pkg/protocol).

Comment: You can define `\protocol{YYYY-MM-DD}`, `\present{Name,Name,Name}`, `\begin{points} \point .. \point .. \point .. \end{points}`, and `\finished{Name}` to output exactly what you just wrote.

Comment: Try the [tag:meetingmins] package.